# js clone htmlElementobject how to operate dom

Tags: javascript

[image]

Why ooo can operate DOM, how browsers recognize ooo, I just copy the DOM property method to ooo

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

for copying DOM elements use cloneNode method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

```
var ooo = document.getElementById('box').cloneNode();
```

Comment: why do I do just like my method, the ooo can also operate the DOM like change it's background and so on. but the ooo isn't a elementNode, How do browsers deal with DOM?

Comment: document.getElementById() will always return a DOM element. if you copy all the attributes it is not the same. var oo = {} can't be DOM element. You can create scratch element by var oo = document.createElement("div");

Comment: if you use cloneNode you can change the style on ooo too. browser has a tree of DOM elements and if you want to manipulate it, you have to use methods defined for doing that and not your own

Comment: Since ooo is not a DOM element, it also operates the style of DOM. Isn't it only DOM that can operate DOM? This is where I'm most confused

Comment: ooo is a DOM element (in cloneNode solution - not yours), what else it can be?

Comment: you should get more info about DOM context - see the: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Comment: I konw in cloneNode solution ooo is a DOM element,but I use my method the ooo can also manipulate this Dom of it's style

Comment: I doubt that your solution is working... try it with cloneNode and ooo.style.fontSize = "32px"; will work. Off course you need to appendChild or insertBefore ooo element to display it in browser. Study the DOM context I shared for you before. You don't need only one anwser, you need to get a context

Comment: Thank you very much